# ConfirmBehavior dosen't support Ajax rendreing

Tags: primefaces

After an Ajax update of a button with a `ConfirmBehavior`, all Confirm dialog attributes (Header, Message, Icon) becomes Null.

Its look like thoses values are evaluated during the buildView phase only (applyMetadata function)

In the `getHeader()`/`getMessage()`/`getIcon()` methods of the ConfirmBehavior there is no evaluation of expression.

How to get the real expression at this point ? (to evaluate it during the render phase)

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution

```
public class ConfirmBehavior extends ClientBehaviorBase {

    private String header;
    private String message;
    private String icon;

    @Override
    public String getScript(ClientBehaviorContext behaviorContext) {
        FacesContext context = behaviorContext.getFacesContext();
        UIComponent component = behaviorContext.getComponent();
        String source = component.getClientId(context);

        if(component instanceof Confirmable) {          
            String headerExpr = (String) component.getAttributes().get("confirm_header");
            if (headerExpr!=null)
                this.header = (String) ContextUtil.eval(context, headerExpr);
            String messageExpr = (String) component.getAttributes().get("confirm_message");         
            if (messageExpr!=null)
                this.message = (String) ContextUtil.eval(context, messageExpr);
            String iconExpr = (String) component.getAttributes().get("confirm_icon");           
            if (iconExpr!=null)
                this.icon = (String) ContextUtil.eval(context, iconExpr);
            String script = "PrimeFaces.confirm({source:'" + source + "',header:'" + getHeader() + "',message:'" + getMessage() + "',icon:'" + getIcon()  + "'});return false;";
            ((Confirmable) component).setConfirmationScript(script);

            return null;
        }
        else {
            throw new FacesException("Component " + source + " is not a Confirmable. ConfirmBehavior can only be attached to components that implement org.primefaces.component.api.Confirmable interface");
        }

    }
...
}
```